# Unable to get distinct values in the table: Get error message "Error performing query operation" most of times

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-rest-api

We are using ArcGIS REST Services (Version- 10.71), for querying distinct values in the table, however, most of the times our query return error: “Error performing query operation”  with 500 error code.

In the table there are total 330094 records, of which only 24420 should be returned with given where clause (Play='Permian Delaware Tight, US').
Moreover, there are only 201 distinct values in the given field('operator') when aforementioned where clause is applied.

Mainly my query contains following constraints:

```
where = Play='Permian Delaware Tight, US'
outFields = 'operator'
returnGeometry = false
returnDistinctValues = true (optional, even if we set this to false, we're still getting the issue)
returnCountOnly = true
```

Overall request URL:

```
{our RestURL}       
/query?where=Play+%3d+%27Permian+Delaware+Tight%2c+US%27&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=
&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=operator
&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=
&returnDistinctValues=true&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=True&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=
&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&resultOffset=
&resultRecordCount=&returnTrueCurves=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&quantizationParameters=
&returnCentroid=false&sqlFormat=none&resultType=none&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson
```

I believe this is simple query and should not throw exception. Please let me know if I’m missing anything here.

Layer settings are as follows: (which I believe are correct for given query to run)

```
Supports Advanced Queries: true
# Advanced Query Capabilities:
Supports Statistics: true
Supports OrderBy: true
Supports Distinct: true
Supports Pagination: true
Supports TrueCurve: true
Supports Returning Query Extent: true
Supports Query With Distance: true
Supports Sql Expression: true
Supports Query With ResultType: true
Supports Returning Geometry Centroid: false
Supports Binning LOD: false
Supports Query With LOD Spatial Reference: false
```

Comment: If you tweak your WHERE clause you can determine if you are running into a limit at 200 or 100 distinct values.

Comment: not sure if there is such limitation, however, this doesn't help I still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

This developers page, https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/error-handling-with-sync-operations.htm, says:

> For example, an HTTP status of 500 indicates an internal server error
> (for example, the server has gone down). Once the issue has been
> resolved, the client can reissue the request.

You or your admin can try stopping and restarting the service.

Or it might be related to the default query file size as explained here, https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011736.